# Jqgrid Pagination

Tags: jquery, jqgrid-asp.net

Pagination is not working. Here is my code for the grid

```
$('#tblGridId').jqGrid({
        url: 'JHandler/PakedOpening.ashx',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype:'Get',
    colNames: ['Item Send', 'Use Lot No.', 'Packing Type', 'Design No.', 'Bundle', 'Thaan', 'Quantity', 'Action'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'ITEMSEND', width: 150, sortable: true },
        { name: 'LOTNO.', width: 70, sortable: true },
        { name: 'PACKINGTYPE', width: 70, sortable: true },
        { name: 'DESIGNNO.', width: 70, sortable: true },
        { name: 'BUNDLE', width: 70, sortable: true },
        { name: 'THAAN', width: 70, sortable: true },
        { name: 'QUANTITY', width: 70, sortable: true },
    //    { name: 'WAREHOUSE', width: 100, sortable: true },
        { name: 'ACTION', width: 50, sortable: false },
    ],
    height: 'auto',
    autowidth: 'auto',
    rownum: 20,
    LoadOnce: true,
    rowList: [50, 100, 200, 400],
    pager: 'tblGridPager',
    sortName: 'ItemSend',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'asc',
    caption: 'Opening',
    emptyrecords: 'No Records To Display',
    jsonreader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        Id:'0',
    },
    multiselect: false
});

$('#tblGridId').jqGrid('navGrid', '#tblGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, paging:true, search: false });
```

`

Comment: Mistake in pager: 'tblGridPager' declaration. Should be  pager: '#tblGridPager',

Comment: i have done that already but still its not working

Comment: have you created a div with id as "tblGridPager"???? Please share your html code as well.

Comment: <table id="tblGridId" >
                            </table>
                            <div id="tblGridPager" style="text-align:center" >
                            </div>

Comment: is there any pagination code to be written in load data function that i have created?

Comment: Check out the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QEzhr/1430/

Comment: saw that it didn't helped

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution http://jsfiddle.net/QEzhr/1435/

```
    <table id="tblGridId" > </table> <div id="tblGridPager" style="text-align:center" > </div>
```

Comment: i think u misunderstood...i m trying to ask about pagination...i have already loaded data in grid but pagination is not working

Comment: its working with local data but when i try with data from my sql server it doesn't work